# How to replace variable name and variable value from string?

Tags: php, replace

I have a Google Forms Prefilled URL

```
$input = "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSe8aZbfXa2IRRzK6hPTDKvAf_Oa8chTMrX8wkkYcuVHGs-vuA/viewform?usp=pp_url&entry.1064398956=NAME&entry.1318807391=TELEPHONE";
$pars = parse_url($input);
$values = $pars["query"];
$values = str_replace("entry.", "", $values);
$values = str_replace("usp=pp_url&", "", $values);
```

With this code I get values as

```
1064398956=NAME&1318807391=TELEPHONE
```

Because the numbers (entry id) are always different, I use default values (like NAME, TELEPHONE), and these would be storaged to mySQL database like this:

```
Id  ||  NAME       || VALUE
================================
1   || 1064398956  || 1318807391
```

To upload a row to that mysql database I have the query:

```
    INSERT INTO TABLE (ID, NAME, VALUE) VALUES (1, $NAME, $VALUE)
```

Based on the following string, how i can find values $NAME and $VALUE?

```
1064398956=NAME&1318807391=TELEPHONE
```

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: Edit the PHP code in a text editor?  It's not clear to me what you mean or what you're asking here.

Comment: ${$NAME} = "NAME" ?

Comment: It's confusing!

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: I want to get from Prefilled Google Forms entry ID-s. The values are by default, but the entry ID number is always changing. I have the mySQL database where the entry ID numbers are collected by default values. I have the string: "1064398956=NAME&1318807391=TELEPHONE" I need to get the variable Telephone with its value as 1318807391

Comment: `parse_str` and `array_flip`, and yes, arrays in general.

Comment: @userxöa You should put that comment in the question. It's completely different from what you asked, there are no PHP variables in that string.

Comment: You can also use `explode()` to split the string at `&` and `=` characters.

Comment: Added background. I hope, this helps. Thanks for helping :)

Comment: The comment by @mario should work for you. Have you tried it? https://3v4l.org/8CstD You then can iterate over `$output` and use the `key` as the var name and the `value` as you would.

Comment: Hi! I tested it now as you provided me a sample, and it worked. Thanks, chris85! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The @mario and @chris85 solution that worked:

```
$string = '1064398956=NAME&1318807391=TELEPHONE';
parse_str($string, $output);
print_r(array_flip($output));
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will switch the var name whit the value ($VALUE variable with 'NAME' value)

```
function get_var_name($vars, $var)
{
  foreach ($vars as $name => $value) {
    if ($value === $var) {
      return $name;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

$NAME = "VALUE";
$$NAME = get_var_name(get_defined_vars(), $NAME);

echo $VALUE; // will print 'NAME'
```

Comment: Multiple variables can have the same value as another.